# How to increase the resolution of a QWidget when using the grab () method

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a Widget, for this example it is a QPushButton.

For which I am using the grab () method, the problem is that when trying to increase the size of the captured image, it appears blurred

Example:
[image]

How can I increase the resolution of the widget by increasing the size of the capture?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication,QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtPrintSupport,QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic

class Teacher(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        #uic.loadUi("gui/Teacher.ui",self)

        #self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        #self.Cerrar.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())

        self.Button = QPushButton(self)
        self.Button.setText("Press")
        self.Button.resize(60,40)
        self.Button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Document())

        self.Rute = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop"

        #self.Print.clicked.connect(lambda:self.Document())

    def Document(self):
        #Name = str(QtCore.QDate.currentDate().toPyDate())
        Printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        Printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        Printer.setOutputFileName(self.Rute+"\\"+"Name1"+".pdf")
        Printer.setFullPage(True)

        Painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        Painter.begin(Printer)
        Widget = self.Button.grab()
        Painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)
        Painter.drawPixmap(10,10,500,500,Widget)
        Painter.end()


app = QApplication([])
f = Teacher()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, simply put, you shouldn't do that.
Most widgets actually use pixmaps internally to draw their contents, and no matter what you'll try to do, you will always end up with pixellated contents.

Besides the pixmap contents of the widget "style", you can't achieve that by means of `grab()`, because it works at the screen resolution.

The only possible alternative is to use [`render()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render) (which considers the *paint device* it's going to be rendered) with a QImage, that allows setting.

```
class Teacher(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Press")
        self.button.resize(60,40)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.document)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.path = QtCore.QDir("/tmp")

    def document(self):
        printer = QtPrintSupport.QPrinter()
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtPrintSupport.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName(self.path.absoluteFilePath("Name1.pdf"))
        printer.setFullPage(True)

        ratio = 5
        size = self.button.size()
        image = QtGui.QImage(size.width() * ratio, size.height() * ratio, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        image.setDevicePixelRatio(ratio)
        self.button.render(image)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
        painter.scale(ratio, ratio)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, image)
        painter.end()
```

As you can see, the result is "mixed":

[image: rendering result with pixelated borders]

While the text is correctly drawn, the button borders are not, and that's due to the aforementioned pixmap contents the style uses to draw widgets.

A solution would be to paint *all* widgets by yourself (by subclassing each widget you're going to paint and override their paintEvent methods), but this can be *very* tricky for complex widgets like list views.
The "midway" would be to use a custom stylesheet for the whole application, but that's not *that* an easy task: complex widgets require that you provide the *whole* css styling (that's the case of widgets that have scroll areas, like item views, for which you'll also have to provide the styling for *every* element of the scrollbars too).
Obviously, this will also mean that you'll get a program that will *not* be graphically consistent with your OS.

```
app = QApplication([])
app.setStyleSheet('''
    QPushButton {
        border: 1px solid darkGray;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        min-width: 80px;
    }
    QPushButton:hover{
        border-style: outset;
    }
    QPushButton:pressed {
        border-style: inset;
    }
    '''
```

On the other hand, you'll get an almost perfectly drawn widget, even at large scales:

[image: smooth rendered button]

PS: I've changed a bit your code, mostly to use lowercase object names and functions as PEP8 style guide suggests, for which capitalized names should only be used for class names (and is also considered a convention especially on Q&A sites like StackOverflow).